# Convert HashMap key value (String) to Vector <String>?

Tags: java, vector, hashmap

I have a hashmap declared as :

```
HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

I'm declaring a Vector as :

```
 Vector<String> productList = new Vector<String>();
```

Now, I'm trying to add the keys into the vector :

```
  Set set = hm.entrySet();
  // Get an iterator
  Iterator i = set.iterator();
  // Display elements
  while(i.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
     //System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
     productList.add(me.getKey());
     //System.out.println(me.getValue());
  }

//hm is the HashMap holding the keys and values.
```

When I compile the code it gives the following error:

```
ProductHandler.java:52: error: no suitable method found for add(Object)
     productList.add(me.getKey());
                ^
method Collection.add(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to String)
```

Do we need to convert the values to String type before trying to add it to the vector? Am I missing out on something?

Comment: You can use `Vector<String> productList = new Vector<String>(hm.keySet());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can do it in one line with the [`Vector(Collection<? extends E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector-java.util.Collection-) constructor and a call to [`Map.keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) like

```
Vector<String> productList = new Vector<>(hm.keySet());
```

Second, you should prefer an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)<sup>1</sup>

```
List<String> productList = new ArrayList<>(hm.keySet());
```

<sup>1<sub>Unless you're sharing this list with multiple threads, adding synchronization with a `Vector` is a *cost*.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks that worked! Just curious, how does a Vector map the values of a Set after the hm.keySet() returns the keys?

Comment: Here it's equivalent to adding all of the elements in the `keySet` to the `Collection`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use raw types.

Your code can be much simpler with enhanced for loop :

```
  for(String key : hm.keySet()) {
     productList.add(key);
  }
```

or

```
  for(Map.Entry<String,Double> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
     productList.add(entry.getKey());
  }
```